# dynamically concatenate HLS videos

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I was wondering how I could dynamically concatenate HLS videos for the following usecase:

Each video has a duration of 5 minutes. The user requests all files for the timespan covering 1pm-2pm (i.e. 12 files). Could I then just concatenate the contents of the .m3u8 files to get one continuous stream?

best regards, Chris

Answer (score 0):

It works if you put `EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY` tags at the boundaries of each video to account for timestamp discontinuities and/or changes in format.

Example from the HLS [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-AD_PLAYLIST__DISCONTINUITIES_) for ad insertion:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:10.0,
ad0.ts
#EXTINF:8.0,
ad1.ts
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:10.0,
movieA.ts
#EXTINF:10.0,
movieB.ts
```

See more in the [HLS specifications](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-20.txt)